# Troubles with NSFilemanager in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am trying to read a file with Objective C using the following code:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString * myStr = @"/tmp/test.txt";
NSString * myStr4 = @"/tmp/HeaDumper";

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:myStr4] == YES) {
    NSLog(@"%@ exists",myStr4);
    if ([fileManager isReadableFileAtPath:myStr4]) {
        NSLog(@"%@ is Readable",myStr4);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@ not readable",myStr4);
    }

    if ( [fileManager isExecutableFileAtPath:myStr4]) {
        NSLog(@"%@ is Executable",myStr4);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@ Not Executable",myStr4);
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"%@ file not exist",myStr4);
}

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:myStr] == YES) {
    NSLog(@"%@ exists",myStr);
    if ([fileManager isReadableFileAtPath:myStr]) {
        NSLog(@"%@ is Readable",myStr);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@ not readable",myStr);
    }

    if ( [fileManager isExecutableFileAtPath:myStr]) {
        NSLog(@"%@ is Executable",myStr);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@ Not Executable",myStr);
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"%@ file not exist",myStr);
}
```

and I receive this output:

- 2020-05-29 15:05:12.009759+0100 readfile2[7923:967693] /tmp/HeaDumper exists
- 2020-05-29 15:05:12.009855+0100 readfile2[7923:967693] /tmp/HeaDumper not readable
- 2020-05-29 15:05:12.009900+0100 readfile2[7923:967693] /tmp/HeaDumper Not Executable
- 2020-05-29 15:05:12.009939+0100 readfile2[7923:967693] /tmp/test.txt exists
- 2020-05-29 15:05:12.009986+0100 readfile2[7923:967693] /tmp/test.txt not readable
- 2020-05-29 15:05:12.010022+0100 readfile2[7923:967693] /tmp/test.txt Not Executable

However:

1. the files exist
2. the files have been `chmod`ded 777 in order to avoid any permission issue (which wasn't the case, but one needs to eliminate all possible co-causes).
3. One is an executable, (**HeaDumper**, stored into `myStr4`) so should be accessible in reading and executing
4. the other (**test.txt**, stored into `myStr`) is a text file, and should be accessible at least in reading.

Where is the problem, here?

Comment: I wonder if this is because you are not allowed to just give an arbitrary pathname like this. You must pass through the file manager's list of known available directories, and you  probably must take sandboxing into account.

Comment: The root of the issue was actually sandboxing. Thanks Matt.

Comment: Yay! I wasn't entirely sure about this, and that suggests that others might not be sure, so please feel free to answer your own question. Totally legal, and might help others.